# Triangle with $x-y\le0, 4x+5y\le c, x\ge 0, 0\le y\le3$

Tags: linear-algebra

$$x-y\le 0$$
$$4x+5y\le c$$
$$x\ge 0$$
$$0\le y\le3$$
what is $c$ so, these lines form a triangle? $c$ = integer

from 
$x-y\le 0$ and $4x+5y\le c$

$9x\le c$

but i can't draw for line $ 4x+5y\le c$

what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conditions $x-y\le0,x\ge0,0\le y\le3$ define a triangular area $A$ with vertices $(0,0),(0,3),(3,3)$.

The other condition is $y\le 0.2c-0,8x$ which defines the area to the left of the downward-sloping line $y=0.2c-0.8x$.

If the line intersects the $y$ axis below the orign then that area is disjoint from $A$, so we get nothing. If it intersects it between 0 and 3, then the intersection is triangular (but not the whole of $A$). As it moves further up the $y$-axis we get a quadrilateral area until the line passes through the point $(3,3)$. At that point we get the whole of $A$, which is triangular, and that remains the case as it moves further up.

So you just have to identify the three critical values of $c$, call them $c_1,c_2$ and $c_3$.

For $c\le c_1$ there is no area and hence no triangle. For $c_1<c\le c_2$ there is a triangular area. For $c_2<c<c_3$ the area is not triangular. For $c_3\le c$ it is again triangular.

Can you complete?

[image]

My answer would be: triangle for $0<c\le15$ and for $27\le c$

---

In response to a comment below:

Remember, these are *inequalities*, not equations. So we are interested in a 2D **area**, rather than the **sides** of a triangle. The conditions $0\le x\le y\le3$ define the yellow area in the picture. But we also have to satisfy the equation $4x+5y\le c$ which defines a half plane under one of the lines in a family of parallel lines (4 of which are illustrated above). So **any** value of $c\ge 27$ gives a line *above* the triangle. If $15<c<27$ we get a quadrilateral (the yellow triangle with the left hand corner cut off). If $0<c\le15$ we get a triangle (the bottom part of the yellow triangle, formed by slicing off the top part). If $c\le0$ we get nothing at all - [to be more precise, we get nothing for $c<0$ or a single point for $c=0$, but that hardly counts as a triangle].

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Many thanks. A stupid typo, which wrecked the answer! Fixed, I hope.

Comment: C>15, 0<c<15, ? The options are 12 15 16 20 27

Comment: Why 27<= c?  So the answer should be 27 or 15?